# Why is my linear gradient background animation is broken on mobile?

Tags: javascript, mobile, linear-gradients

As the tittle says. I coded [this](http://fn-up.com) website but am having problems with the background animation on mobile. I will post the javascript for the gradient below, but can someone check out the source and please help me understand why it is not working.

Let me know if you need more information and I will gladly supply it.

Javascript for background animation

```
var angle = -20, color = "#2b2b2b", colors = "#000", font = "rgba(102, 102, 102, .3)", shadow = "4px 4px 40px #000";

var changeBackground = function() {
  angle = angle + .3
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(" + angle + "deg, " + colors + ", " + color + ", " + colors + ",  " + color + ",  " + colors + ",  " + color + ", " + colors + ",  " + color + ", " + colors + ",  " + color + ", " + colors + ", " + color;
  requestAnimationFrame(changeBackground)
}

var changeFont = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('h2').forEach(h2 => h2.style.color = font);
}

var changeShadow = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('h2').forEach(h2 => h2.style.textShadow = shadow);
}


changeBackground()
changeFont()
changeShadow();

document.querySelector('.myBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
  color = (color != "#2b2b2b") ? "#2b2b2b" : "#f1f9d4";
  colors = (colors != "#000") ? "#000" : "#759ef3";
  font = (font != "rgba(102, 102, 102, .3)") ? "rgba(102, 102, 102, .3)" : "rgba(178, 117, 164, .3)";
  shadow = (shadow != "4px 4px 40px #000") ? "4px 4px 40px #000" : "4px 4px 40px #fff";
  changeFont()
  changeShadow();
})

document.querySelector(".myBtn").addEventListener("click", function () {
  document.body.classList.toggle("light")
})
```

Comment: Did you try experimenting with `@keyframes`?  That might be more reliable.

Comment: No I haven't tried it yet. I will give it a go